# RAM compatability with motherboard - not POSTing in Dual Channel setup

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a problem in installing 2 DIMMs of G.SKill memory in my motherboard.

To start with

- motherboard is 
  http://www.msi.com/product/mb/KA790GX.html#/?div=Detail
- and the RAM is 
  http://geizhals.at/de/g-skill-dimm-kit-4gb-pc2-8000u-cl5-5-5-15-ddr2-1000-f2-8000cl5d-4gbpq-a286178.html

The scenario is like this:

The RAM works in Single Channel mode, installed on Dimm 0 and 3. But as soon as I try to install it on Dimm 0 and Dimm 1 (for Dual Channel) it simple do not POST, just the CPU Fan power up but no signal on screen.

Additional tips

- BIOS is flashed to the latest version.
- I tested with another motherboard, same problem.
- I tested with another pair of identical RAM, same problem.
- Also tested with another PSU, same problem.

That means, I'm getting crazy! :)

Could it be the 2.1v rating? Or because the RAM is PC2-8000?

Comment: try by manually setting the ram timing lower (to higher numbers) when it is working, then shift the ram around.  Chances are you can get it to "work" , problem is if you clear the cmos or go back to auto, you will be right back where you were again.

Comment: What does the manual say?  Does your motherboard support 2.1v PC2-8000 memory?  If you tried another motherboard the likelyhood of defective memory raises but since you have second set and they experience the same problem its unlikely.

Comment: The specification for the motherboard indicate the memmory is not capatable with your motherboard.   **DDR2 DIMMs (240pin / 1.8V)**

Comment: Why have you deleted your old question? I told you that there is no difference between Single and Dual Channel. Set it up in Single Channel and be happy (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DqKmGBKE5iAJ:superuser.com/questions/630830/ram-compatability-with-motherboard-not-posting-in-dual-channel-setup+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de)

Comment: I sent you a reply about that already. For me it does not actually matter if it's in single or dual channel, I just need 8GB of RAM in my mobo. To be able to install 8GB of RAM I would have to use all 4 dimm slots (x2GB modules)

Comment: everyone.. I'm still reading and evaluating then I will send further feedback...

Comment: @OliverMGrech - The alternative to using single channel is to use the correct hardware for the job. Memory which requires 300mv more then you can supply isn't the correct hardware. Your lucky it even works in single channel, many reasons it would, far more reasons why it shouldn't.  I also wish you didn't delete your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory your attempting to use is not supported by your motherboard.  The memory you purchase is expecting 300mv additional voltage then your motherboard can supply.  Of course if you have the memory in the wrong slots then the system also wouldn't even turn on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your post, I read the above on my manual already but missed the bottom "Memory Support" voltage thing...
On TomsHardware I saw an Article stating two things, one which says that it is possible to lower the frequency of the RAM + the Voltage and the other one is that "if it boots with one module there should be a way to make it work with 4 modules on all slots).
Any further help or shed of light will be appreciated!

Comment: @OliverMGrech - You can undervoltage memory but 300mv is pretty serious undervoltage.  Your hardware also has to provide that capability and your motherboard unlikely supports doing so anyways.

Comment: hmm.. I understand... anyone suggest a mobo for those modules? (Am2+ CPU, Phenom)

Comment: @OliverMGrech - We don't do shopping recomendations here at Superuser.

Comment: oh oki :) anyways.. thanks all for your help.. selecting an answer now..